# How to create an index on CASE expression in Oracle

Tags: oracle, index

I am trying to create an index on an oracle table as it follows

```
DECLARE MGMT_ID NUMBER;
        SSHKEY_MGMT_ID NUMBER;

BEGIN
    SELECT ID INTO MGMT_ID FROM POLICY_SETS WHERE POLICY_SET_NAME = 'MGMT';
    SELECT ID INTO SSHKEY_MGMT_ID FROM POLICY_SETS WHERE POLICY_SET_NAME = 'SSHKEY_MGMT';

    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PASSWORD_OBJECT_UI_1
        ON PASSWORD_OBJECTS (ACCOUNTNAME, ADDRESS,
        (CASE
            WHEN POLICY_SET = MGMT_ID OR POLICY_SET = SSHKEY_MGMT_ID THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
        )
    );
    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

And the problem is that I get the error :

```
SQL Error [6550] [65000]: ORA-06550: line 8, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:
```

Lastly, but not least I have to mention that the goal of this script is to ​create a limitation on table PASSWORD_OBJECTS (which will ensure that there will unicity for the combination of columns (ACCOUNTNAME, ADDRESS), with only one exception :

- the case when 2 entries (lines) of the table have same combination of columns (ACCOUNTNAME, ADDRESS) and one entry has column POLICY_SET in (MGMT, SSHKEY_MGMT) and the other entry has column POLICY_SET not in (MGMT, SSHKEY_MGMT).

That would be the only case when two lines can have same values in combination (ACCOUNTNAME, ADDRESS).

Any ideas? I am open to other technical solution if you think my idea with the index is KO.

Comment: If you want to run DDL in an anonymous block, you'd need to use dynamic SQL.  Unless your primary keys differ across environments, I'd just do the `create index` statement outside of an anonymous block with hard-coded IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table DDL and sample data would help in checking whether this does what you want, but a syntactically working version would be:

```
declare
    mgmt_id          number;
    sshkey_mgmt_id   number;
    create_index_sql varchar2(200);
begin
    select id into mgmt_id
    from   policy_sets
    where  policy_set_name = 'MGMT';

    select id into sshkey_mgmt_id
    from   policy_sets
    where  policy_set_name = 'SSHKEY_MGMT';

    create_index_sql :=
    'create unique index password_object_ui_1 on password_objects'||
    '( accountname, address'||
    ', (case when policy_set in ('||mgmt_id||','||sshkey_mgmt_id||') then 1 else 0 end) )';
    
    dbms_output.put_line(create_index_sql);
    
    execute immediate create_index_sql;
end;
```

which gives (with a bit of reformatting):

```
create unique index password_object_ui_1 on password_objects
( accountname
, address
, (case when policy_set in (123, 321) then 1 else 0 end) )
```

Comment: Well contrats ! It works... I think these lines made the magic happen : dbms_output.put_line(create_index_sql);
execute immediate create_index_sql;